# How to create ball moving under blanket effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation

I am trying to get an animation effect of a ball moving under a blanket with some resistance or a round object protuding out of a flat surface.  Below is what I've been able to do so far and what I want to achieve. For now I've used a different colour for the ball to make things a more visible.

[image]

Comment: You can create animations in Illustrator?

Comment: @KSPR No, I will use flash for the animation.  I am mainly interested in the missing images that would give the effect of an animation transition.

Comment: I think you are trying to create something like this,  If so, please let me know, then I will create an answer for this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/epeuf54kqsueezq/Untitled-1.gif?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. Here's a video of what I would do.

https://www.dropbox.com/sc/quc1bgda0x8mh72/AABuk811PlV7OX3DItcXwFuxa

- Create a shape that simulates material drooping over the ball using
  the pen tool:
- Click on the top edge of the blanket shape and pull a handle out horizontally to the right
- click on a point halfway up the ball
  [image]
- finish the shape, making sure it overlaps the ball
  [image]
- Copy the shape and transform > reflect (vertically)
- Position these shapes to merge seamlessly with the edge of the ball
  [image]
- Merge the shapes using the pathfinder tool
  [image]
- Use that shape as a symbol in front of the blanket. As
  it's the same colour as the blanket, viewer won't be able to
  distinguish it as a separate shape. It will appear as though the blanket is being distorted.

Comment: in case that dropbox link disappears in the future, could you write down how to create the shape?

Comment: Have added screenshots of the video

Comment: You know reflect is available as a tool so you dont need to rearange it as you can reflect around the center of the sphere

Comment: Yes, that would have been more precise.