# how to make image frames that give animation effect of a ball or circular object separating from a thick substance

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation

I am trying to draw individual image frames that when pieced together will to give the animation effect of a ball or circular object coming out of a thick (not necessarily sticky) substance or liquid. The idea is for a protruding object to form a circular object as it separates. How can I create these image frames using  illustrator?

[image]

Comment: if you do not how to draw in ilustrator, probably its better fo use a real fluid simulator like blender.

Comment: The real answer will depend on the "style" you need, the look and feel.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold. Please [edit] your question to explain how this is different from your other question that was already answered. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66338/how-to-create-ball-moving-under-blanket-effect

Comment: @Ryan I just edited the question

Comment: @Ryan the question is still marked as duplicate

Comment: I do agree that your edit has differentiated both questions from each other. You do show very little effort, though, and therefore I'll leave this question closed. Please show what you have tried so far and why it didn't live up to your expectations. Think of it this way: the answer to your question would take quite a lot of effort to write. Please show at least that much effort in your question. Now it's like 'I want this real hard thing done, show me how.' It would be a waste to reopen this Q and have it immediately re-closed for lack of effort. Thanks for understanding.